# how to load Matlab's struct (saved with v7.3) in Python

Tags: python, matlab, numpy, struct, scipy

I created a 1X20 struct in Matlab. This struct has 9 fields. The struct is saved in -v7.3 version because of its dimensions (about 3 Giga). one of the fields contains 4D matrix, other contain cell arrays, meaning it is a complex struct.
I would like to know if there is a way to load this struct into Python?

Comment: Do you have a (smaller) sample of the struct?

Comment: Tried `scipy.io.loadmat`?

Comment: `scipy` `loadmat` can load Matlab matrix, cell and struct. - as dictionaries and numpy arrays.  But at some level matlab switched to `HDF5`, in which case you have to use `h5py`.  Do SO search on those terms.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MATLAB v7.3 uses HDF5 storage; `scipy.io.loadmat` cannot handle that

[MATLAB: Differences between .mat versions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4950630/matlab-differences-between-mat-versions)

Instead you have to use `numpy` plus `h5py`

[How to read a v7.3 mat file via h5py?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19310808/how-to-read-a-v7-3-mat-file-via-h5py)

[how to read Mat v7.3 files in python ？](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33509163/how-to-read-mat-v7-3-files-in-python)

and a scattering of more recent questions.

Try that, and come back with a new question it you still have problems sorting out the results.